# How to change the appearance of a button in the ribbon bar?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016, crm-ribbon-workbench

I have added some new buttons in the ribbon bar of Opportunity entity using ribbon workbench solution.

They are all working fine at the moment, but the only issue is that, I am unable to get any option in the ribbon workbench to change the appearance (back color, fore color, font, font style, size, etc) of the button, and so the button doesn't stand out from rest of the buttons.

Any idea on how to change the appearance of buttons in the ribbon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can. You are probably best giving it an icon that stands out.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color scheme or add a logo/icon for customization.

Reference1 : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn949334.aspx
Reference2 : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309639.aspx